# When I run my R in R Studio I get this message about normalising paths. How do i make it dissapear

Tags: r, rstudio

When I run `R` in `R Studio` I constantly get this message every time I start typing - is there any ideas on how to fix the path.

I have tried changing the path to the `R` default path but this does not stop the error. What else does the community suggest to stop this occurring.

The error I get is as follows:

```
Error in normalizePath(path) : 
  path[1]="": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Comment: What is the command line that triggers the error? Are you using  `setwd()`?

Comment: everytmime I type anything it just starts going and running in the background   I tried to setwd to my home drive -  setwd("C:/Users/gambrilr/OneDrive - Centrica/Documents/R Library") and the error continues